# How to populate user profile with django-allauth provider information?

Tags: django, facebook, authentication, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth for my authentication system. I need that when the user sign in, the profile module get populated with the provider info (in my case facebook).

I'm trying to use the pre_social_login signal, but I just don't know how to retrieve the data from the provider auth

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from allauth.socialaccount.signals import pre_social_login

@receiver(pre_social_login)

def populate_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    u = UserProfile( >>FACEBOOK_DATA<< )
    u.save()
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `pre_social_login` signal is sent after a user successfully
authenticates via a social provider, but before the login is actually
processed. This signal is emitted for social logins, signups and when
connecting additional social accounts to an account.

So it is sent before the signup is fully completed -- therefore this not the proper signal to use.

Instead, I recommend you use `allauth.account.signals.user_signed_up`, which is emitted for all users, local and social ones.

From within that handler you can inspect whatever `SocialAccount` is attached to the user. For example, if you want to inspect Google+ specific data, do this:

```
user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='google')[0].extra_data
```

*UPDATE:* the latest development version makes this a little bit more convenient by passing along a `sociallogin` parameter that directly contains all related info (social account, token, ...)

Comment: I had to use it this way: kwargs.get('user').socialaccount_set.filter(provider='facebook').extra_data but when I do so, I get this error: AttributeError at /accounts/facebook/login/callback/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'extra_data' Thanks for the answer man!! Your app is awesome

Comment: Oops, my example was wrong (I just corrected it). I forgot to pick an item from the queryset ([0]), as in: ".filter(...)[0]..."

Comment: The goodies in the sociallogin param can be accessed e.g.     sociallogin.account.get_provider_display(), 
    sociallogin.account.get_avatar_url(), 
    sociallogin.account.get_profile_url(), 
    sociallogin.account.provider,  
    sociallogin.account.extra_data['screen_name'] ...

Answer (score 11):

**Here is a Concrete example of @[pennersr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593944/pennersr) solution :**

Assumming your profile model has these 3 fields: `first_name`, `email`, `picture_url`

***views.py:***

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def populate_profile(sociallogin, user, **kwargs):    

    if sociallogin.account.provider == 'facebook':
        user_data = user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='facebook')[0].extra_data
        picture_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + sociallogin.account.uid + "/picture?type=large"            
        email = user_data['email']
        first_name = user_data['first_name']

    if sociallogin.account.provider == 'linkedin':
        user_data = user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='linkedin')[0].extra_data        
        picture_url = user_data['picture-urls']['picture-url']
        email = user_data['email-address']
        first_name = user_data['first-name']

    if sociallogin.account.provider == 'twitter':
        user_data = user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='twitter')[0].extra_data
        picture_url = user_data['profile_image_url']
        picture_url = picture_url.rsplit("_", 1)[0] + "." + picture_url.rsplit(".", 1)[1]
        email = user_data['email']
        first_name = user_data['name'].split()[0]

    user.profile.avatar_url = picture_url
    user.profile.email_address = email
    user.profile.first_name = first_name
    user.profile.save()
```

If you are confused about those `picture_url` variable in each provider. Then take a look at the docs:

**facebook:**

`picture_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + sociallogin.account.uid + "/picture?type=large"` [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/)

**linkedin:**

`picture_url = user_data['picture-urls']['picture-url']` [Docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

**twitter:**

`picture_url = picture_url.rsplit("_", 1)[0] + "." + picture_url.rsplit(".", 1)[1]` [Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/user-profile-images-and-banners) And for the `rsplit()` take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012228/splitting-on-last-delimiter-in-python-string)

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am doing in this way and taking picture (field) url and google provider(field) as an example.

```
socialaccount_obj = SocialAccount.objects.filter(provider='google', user_id=self.user.id)
   picture = "not available"
   if len(socialaccount_obj):
            picture = socialaccount_obj[0].extra_data['picture']
```

make sure to import : from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do this.

Just add the following to your settings.py. For example, Linked in...

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
'linkedin': {
    'SCOPE': [
        'r_basicprofile',
        'r_emailaddress'
    ],
    'PROFILE_FIELDS': [
        'id',
        'first-name',
        'last-name',
        'email-address',
        'picture-url',
        'public-profile-url',
    ]
}
```

The fields are automatically pulled across.

Comment: How do you know what `SCOPE` and `PROFILE_FIELDS` key-values are available?

Comment: That option is dependent on the providers. Currently it is available only for LinkedIn