# URL String Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

suppose I have a string:

```
some_string = 'https://api.github.com/repos/username/repo-name'
```

How do I move from right to left and stop at the first occurrence of `/` such that what is returned will be `repo-name`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting on last delimiter in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012228/splitting-on-last-delimiter-in-python-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do `some_string.split("/")[-1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
some_string.rfind("/")
```

will return the right-most index of a given character.