# Splitting segment of a string

Tags: python

I am trying to sort through an output of a command line, and I need to snip a certain name that can vary in length, and name. The output I am trying to split is

```
AP Name.......................................... AP-Test
```

The name AP-Test can be any length or name. I was trying to split it by, '.' but that would create a bunch of substrings. I currently store my output into a file called Result.txt, sort through looking for lines with AP Name, but I need to snag the end of the string stored in a list.

```py
 APnames = []                       # AP name lists
 APlinenum = 0                # AP line number index
 APsubstr = "AP Name.".lower()                # searching for "AP Name".

 fileA = open("Results.txt", 'a+')
       for line in fileA:
           APlinenum += 1
           if line.lower().find(APsubstr) != -1:    # if case-insensitive match,
           APnames.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

       fileA.close()

APname = "the actual AP-name"
```

There is the issue of if the AP name contains a period, it would be split.

The expected output would be the string APname is the exact name and no other characters.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: "The name AP-Test can be any length or name". Can that name contain a period?

Comment: The quality of the answer depends on how good you are able to specify what the lines look like and what you want to extract from it. For example, if the word is always on the 51st character of the line, than it's easy to remove the first 50 characters. If the separator is alwasy multiple consecutive periods, and the parts before and after it do not contain multiple consecutive periods, than you can use a regular expression. But if there can be periods anywhere in the line and the lenghths can also vary, then how would you know what/where the name is?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just count the dots and split by the result?

```
num_of_dots = txt.count('.')
txt.split('.'*num_of_dots)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to split by "at least one dot":

```
import re
print(re.split('\.+', APnames))
```

Here `\.` means a literal `.` (instead of "any character", which is what `.` usually means in regex), and `+` means "any number of times in a row, but at least once".

Example usage:

```
>>> re.split('\.+', 'a....b')
['a', 'b']
>>> re.split('\.+', 'a.......b')
['a', 'b']
```

If the strings themselves can contain dots, you could require more than one dot to do the split, by changing the regex to something like `\.{3,}` to require at least 3 dots.

Comment: I believe when the length of ap name increases, the amount of dots decrease

Comment: Would            APstr = [(re.split('\.+', APnames))]    work?

Comment: Depends what you want it to do.. that gives you a nested list. I think you probably want `re.split('\.+', APnames)[1]` to get the string *after* the dots.. or change it to `[0]` to get the first string.

Comment: I recievded an error of expected string or buffer, do I assign re.split to a string ?

Comment: `re.split` gives you a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012237

```
string.rsplit('delimeter',1)[1]
```