# Split() in python how to use if there is condition has to skip for some value

Tags: python, pandas, split

I'm new in python and I'd like to separate datas in one column which includes film name with release year to multiple columns, so I found split function.

Data is organized as Title (Year).

What I tried in python was:

```
movies['title'].str.split('(', 1, expand = True)
```

Exception happened for those cases below:

> City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1999)
>
> City of Lost Children, The.        Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1999)

What I had expected was only 1999) goes to the second column.

I need your help!

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe and the expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting on last delimiter in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012228/splitting-on-last-delimiter-in-python-string)

Answer (score 3):

I vote for using `re.findall` here with the pattern `(.*?) \((\d{4})\)`:

```
input = """City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1999)
           City of Lost Children, The. Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1999)"""

matches = re.findall(r'\s*(.*?) \((\d{4})\)', input)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La)', '1999'),
 ('City of Lost Children, The. Cité des enfants perdus, La)', '1999')]
```

Comment: Neat! Perhaps for pandas `df.title.str.findall(r'(.*?) \((\d{4})\)')`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest `pd.Series.str.rsplit`:

Given a series `s`:

```
print(s)
0    City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1999)
1    'City of Lost Children, The. Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1999)'
dtype: object
```

Use `s.str.rsplit('(', 1, expand=True)`:

```
                                                   0      1
0  City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants p...  1999)
1  City of Lost Children, The. Cité des enfants p...  1999)
```