# python pick the date stamp from last part of href

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pickup the last part of every url for further date format processing, how could I do that?

url:
href="/news/this-super-chic-paris-hotel-is-hosting-dinners-in-its-swimming-pool-092520"

result:
092520

Thanks
JC

Comment: `href.rsplit('-', 1)[-1]`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget `rpartition` is another (often forgotten) option, likely to be more efficient here as it doesn't need to allocate a list.

Comment: @AKX: it is, but since OP does not require any of the other parts of the split, it is unnecessary in this case

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Well, a quick benchmark says rpartition is 15% faster in this case, so I'd use it instead.

Comment: @AKX: oh?! That's a good benchmark. Thanks

Comment: Is `href` simply a string? If so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012228/splitting-on-last-delimiter-in-python-string) is a duplicate of your question

Answer (score 0):

Based on this quick benchmark, the fastest obvious method is `rpartition`:

```
import timeit


def t(f, *args):
    timer = timeit.Timer(lambda: f(*args))
    loops, time = timer.autorange()
    print(f"{f.__name__:<10s}: {loops / time:.2f} ops/s ({loops} loops in {time})")


def split(x):
    return x.rsplit("-", 1)[-1]


def part(x):
    return x.rpartition("-")[2]


def rindex(x):
    return x[x.rindex("-") + 1 :]


url = "/news/this-super-chic-paris-hotel-is-hosting-dinners-in-its-swimming-pool-092520"

# Check our implementations for sanity
assert split(url) == part(url) == rindex(url) == "092520"

# Benchmark all of them
t(split, url)
t(part, url)
t(rindex, url)
```

On my Mac (Python 3.8), this outputs

```
split     : 1715847.40 ops/s (500000 loops in 0.291)
part      : 1897332.28 ops/s (500000 loops in 0.264)
rindex    : 1510618.06 ops/s (500000 loops in 0.331)
```

(of which quite some overhead surely is the `lambda` trampoline)

Comment: This is already discussed in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012237/6045800) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012228/splitting-on-last-delimiter-in-python-string)