# How to split once at arithmetic operators starting from the right?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have the string `x = "123+456-789"` and I want to have the `"123+456-"` and `"789"` in separate variables. How can I store the last few characters of a string excluding the character `"-"` in a variable and store the rest in a different variable? This also has to work no matter how many `"+"` or `"-"` or other arithmetic operators are in the string (the last few digits excluding special characters have to be in a separate variable).

I have the last characters but I need the first few to be stored in a different variable:

```
>>> equation_text = "123+456-789"
>>> re.split(r"[+-/*%]", equation_text)[-1]
'789'
```

I used slicing:

```
>>> re.split(r"[+-/*%]", equation_text)[:-1]
['123', '456']
```

But the `"+"` and `"-"` are missing.

Comment: Is the separator always a `+`?

Comment: No, the separator is not always a "+".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012228/splitting-on-last-delimiter-in-python-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters) Since `re` doesn't have a `rsplit`, you could reverse the string, split as the link above shows, adding `maxsplit=1`, and reverse the resulting parts

Comment: What are the other separators? Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @mkrieger1 I need to store the rest of the string. I have the last bit but if I try to store the first part (123+456+), it stores it without the last "+"

Comment: You can find the last separator with `re.findall('\D', equation_text)[-1]` then use @PranavHosangadi's method.

Comment: @mkrieger1  I want the other part of re.split to be in its seperate variable with all the seperators ("+","-","/"). Example:   var = "123+456+789"  -> var1 = "123+456+"  var2 = "789". Sorry if my question wasn't clear, Im bad at explaining

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators. → `parts = re.split(r"([+-/*%])", equation_text)`, `var1 = ''.join(parts[:-1])`, `var2 = parts[-1]`