# how to display image from google account: django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth for user registration in my application via facebook and google. I can display the facebook image of the user. But I have no idea how to do it for google. for facebook, i have followed this tutorial http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

Can somebody suggest me how to display the google account image of user in my website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned here [How to populate user profile with django-allauth provider information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523224/how-to-populate-user-profile-with-django-allauth-provider-information) :

In your server-side code your can try

```
user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='google')[0].extra_data['picture']
```

and in template you can get it like that

```
<img src="{{ user.socialaccount_set.all.0.get_avatar_url }}" />
```

Comment: What if the user hasn't set a picture, will this return `None` or a default picture URL?