# django :Where can I put server side code django

Tags: python, django

I could not really explain it in the title of this question . I need to get the profile image of a user in django allauth. In this question : [how to display image from google account: django-allauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810028/how-to-display-image-from-google-account-django-allauth) , a answer was to use user.socialaccount_set.filter(provider='google')[0].extra_data['picture'] in the server side .
Where is server side ?

Comment: Could you share your views.py? Also, it seems you do not understand fundamental concepts of Django very well, so I recommend you take a tutorial.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to ask about a new problem after trying someone's answer. It's important to keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; the question needs to be about one specific question, that the answers are all answering.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your server-side code in `views.py` inside an app.

Comment: I get an error after putting it in my home page . I put the line above the return render.
Exact error in question.

Comment: It's just because you forgot to indent.