# How to change default extracted data by Provider?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have set up Facebook provide via `django-allauth`. I want to change default extracted data. By default it's `['email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'name']`. I also need user's `birthday` and his `profile photo`.

I have tried to override `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`, but I didn't find there useful methods.

Also I tried to set:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'email',
            'name',
            'birthday',
            'locale',
            'timezone',
            'gender',
        ],
    }
}
```

But nothing happend.

```
class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def populate_user(self,
                      request,
                      sociallogin,
                      data):
        print(data)
        super().populate_user(request, sociallogin, data)
```

`data` still returns only 5 default fields

***UPDATED WITH SOLUTION***

```
from allauth.socialaccount.signals import pre_social_login
from django.dispatch import receiver
from datetime import datetime


@receiver(pre_social_login)
def populate_profile(request, sociallogin, **kwargs):
    if sociallogin.account.provider == "facebook":
        extra_data = sociallogin.account.extra_data
        sociallogin.user.birth_date = datetime.strptime(extra_data['birthday'], '%m/%d/%Y').date()
        sociallogin.user.full_name = extra_data['name']
```

Comment: take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523224/how-to-populate-user-profile-with-django-allauth-provider-information/48182605#48182605

Comment: @Ahtisham Is it based on post signal?

Comment: I used `pre_social_login` signal which gets called after user is authenticated with the provider https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html

Comment: @Ahtisham As I can see you have used `user_signed_up` signal which is used for basic login, not for sociallogin. 
I will not get data on the first login with `pre_social_login` signal because social account with its extra data doesn't exist at that moment

Comment: how are you getting the data ? which signal are you using ?

Comment: @Ahtisham My bad. I tried to acces via `sociallogin.user` not via `sociallogin.account`

Comment: Did my answer on the link which I send you solved your problem ?

Comment: update the question with your view.

Comment: @Ahtisham Yes, your answer on another question helped me